# How to use Uplodify.js with Ember.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ember.js, uploadify

I'm creatinga n app using Ember.js and Ineed to upload files in my app for that I've to use uplodify.js I know how to use uplodify.js in the traditional way but the problem is how can i use the uplodify.js in a app constructed by Ember.js. my current code is given below  I know its not correct

```
Wizard = Em.Application.create({
    ready: function () {
        $('#logoUpload').uploadify({
            'swf': '/Assets/Uplodify/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader': 'Business/FileUpload',
            'buttonText': 'Upload new photo',
            'cancelImg': '/Assets/Uplodify/cancel.png'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @DarinDimitrov please check the updated question I added the current code

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @intuitivepixel I didnt get any error but its not working

Comment: uploadify needs a javascript hash, try to remove the `'` around the keynames, `swf`, `width` etc.

Comment: @intuitivepixel nope I tried that too but no change

Comment: wow. I'm starting to think you're pretty much posting the same question every day

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Yep I did't find a solution yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making this call before anything has been rendered, hence the selector will fail if the #logoUpload is not directly on the page.  You should create an upload view and then call this code in the didInsertElement function of the view.